# Laravel queue:listen queue:work not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3, digital-ocean

I am trying to send an email in background to reduce server response time.

I have created jobs table and failed_jobs table with using
`php artisan queue:table` and `php artisan queue:failed-table`
commands. and also set `QUEUE_DRIVER=database` in .env file.

When I execute following code it creates a job in jobs table.

```
\Mail::later(5, 'email.new-friend-request', ['data'=>$friend_request], function($message) use (&$friend_request){
                    $message->to($friend_request->notifiable->email, $friend_request->notifiable->name)->from('info@example.com','ABC')->subject('New Friend Request');
                });
```

But when I execute `php artisan queue:listen` or `php artisan queue:work` command. It neither processes the jobs saved in jobs table nor it gives any output on console.

However when I check jobs table, the attempts field of job keep incrementing. But job is not getting processed.

Also when I send mail directly using following code ie without adding it to queue. The mail got sent without any problem.

```
\Mail::send('email.new-friend-request', ['data'=>$friend_request], function($message) use (&$friend_request){
                        $message->to($friend_request->notifiable->email, $friend_request->notifiable->name)->from('info@example.com','ABC')->subject('New Friend Request');
                    });
```

**Update**

I tried sending email without any data and it also works without any issue.
ie

```
\Mail::later(5, 'email.new-friend-request', [], function($message) use (&$friend_request){
                        $message->to($friend_request->notifiable->email, $friend_request->notifiable->name)->from('info@example.com','ABC')->subject('New Friend Request');
                    });
```

Comment: if possible, set your QUEUE_DRIVER to sync, then write a quite command to dispatch the job, that way you can see an errors that might be stopping the job. Also have you added a failed function to your job?

Comment: What do you mean by quite Command?

Comment: `storage/logs/laravel.log` it sounds like some of your logic is failing when creating the email.

Comment: storage/logs/laravel.log fie is blank

Comment: meant quick command, mis-spell

Comment: There is no problem in dispatching the job. I can see the job in jobs table. But its not getting processed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it, the problem was with Eloquent relations.
When emails are qued then Eloquent model objects need to be serialized. Therefore once a model object is serialized then one can not access relations.

So I just tried eager loading model relations and also converted my model objects into an array using `toArray()` method and then jobs started being processed.

That is before calling

```
\Mail::later(5, 'email.new-friend-request', ['data'=>$friend_request], function($message) use (&$friend_request){
                    $message->to($friend_request->notifiable->email, $friend_request->notifiable->name)->from('info@example.com','ABC')->subject('New Friend Request');
                });
```

I eager loaded all the relations on `$friend_request` object.

For Example:-

```
$friend_request = FriendRequest::with('notifiable')->find($request_id);
```